# Altair add log linear regression to chart with selection

Tags: python, altair

I have an Altair scatter chart, plotting a date vs a quantity.
The chart includes a selection menu, to highlight points from different domains.

[image]

I would like to add a logistic regression on top of it, with `transform_regression`.

However I get an error when doing it.

This is my code:

```
import altair as alt
alt.themes.enable('fivethirtyeight')
selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['Domain'], bind='legend')
chart = alt.Chart(df, width=1100, height=600, 
          title="Parameter count of ML systems through time")\
.mark_point(size=120, filled=False).encode(
  x=alt.X('Publication date:T'),
  y=alt.Y('Parameters:Q',scale=alt.Scale(type='log'), axis=alt.Axis(format=".1e")),
  color='Domain',
  shape = 'Domain',
  tooltip=['System', 
           'Reference', 
           'Publication date', 
           alt.Tooltip('Parameters', format=".1e"), 
           'Domain'],
  opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.2))
).add_selection(
    selection
)

regression = chart.transform_regression(
    on="Publication date", regression="Parameters", groupby=["Domain"]
).mark_line()

alt.layer(chart, regression).configure_axis(labelFontSize=20,titleFontSize=30).configure_legend(
    titleFontSize=20,
    labelFontSize =18,
    gradientLength=400,
    gradientThickness=30,
    symbolSize = 130
)
```

This is the error I get: `Javascript Error: Duplicate signal name: "selector027_tuple" This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback.`

I cannot understand the output of the javascript console but it shows this:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Javascript Error: Duplicate signal name: "selector028_tuple"<br>This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback.
Promise.catch (async)
displayChart @ VM1182:32
(anonymous) @ VM1182:45
load (async)
(anonymous) @ VM1182:19
loadScript @ VM1182:15
(anonymous) @ VM1182:43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the regression chart is based on the point chart which already have the selection added, you are adding it twice when you are layering these two charts. Instead, create the points chart without the selection and add it to only one of the charts in layer:

```
alt.layer(chart.add_selection(selection), regression)
```

or once to the layered chart:

```
alt.layer(chart, regression).add_selection(selection)
```